# fopen with string variable fails

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a small program that saves some information on a file, taking input from the user for the content and name of the file. For some reason, I am unable to save file_name into FILE *open.

This works when input a string as the file name; open = fopen("filename.txt","w"); but not when I try to input string as a variable. I have looked all over and cannot find an answer anywhere.

I have included stdio.h and string.h

```
int main (){


    FILE *open;

    char first_name[16],last_name[21];
    char save_name[30],ext[10];
    char file_name[40];
    int a,b;

    printf("This program will take your name and save it in a file.\n");
    printf("Insert your first name:");
    scanf("%s",&first_name);
    printf("Insert your last name:");
    scanf("%s",&last_name);


    do{

        printf("Insert file name with extension:");
        scanf("%[^.].%s", &save_name, &ext);
        //Takes filename lenght, minus the dot
        a = (int)strlen(save_name)-1;
        b = (int)strlen(ext);
        sprintf(file_name,"%s.%s",save_name,ext);

    }while(a>8 || b>3);

//This is where my problem lies...

    open = fopen(file_name,"w");

    if(open==NULL){
        printf("File %s failed to open, shutting down...",file_name);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(open, "%s %s",first_name,last_name);
        printf("\n\nSave successful! File was saved as: %s",file_name);
    }

    fclose(open);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your `printf` at the end print as `file_name`? Does it have the correct value?

Comment: First of all, what is the input you give the program? Then what is the output? And if you fail to open the file, what does e.g. printing `strerror(errno)` report? And is the file you want to open in the correct directory? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "open" is a syscall and is not a good name for any variable.

Comment: @ulix Only in POSIX systems. But I agree that it's a bad name, but on other grounds (it's not descriptive).

Comment: @uneven_mark - Tested your diagnostic … it looked deceptively correct until I noticed the newline wasn't being printed elsewhere!

Comment: uneven_mark printf prints out the correct filename, based on user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `file_name` has a leading newline character in it! The newline is being added by your `scanf()` call with the `"%[^.]"` format (but I'm not entirely sure why). It seems that using `%s` for string input automatically removes this but `%[^.]` will accept all characters except `.` (including whitespace). Use this to fix it (skipping the newline):

```
scanf("\n%[^.].%s", &save_name, &ext);
```

Comments welcome as to where this newline comes from - it's news to me!

PS: You don't need the `- 1` in your calculation of `a`, as the dot is never read into `save_name`.

Comment: My guess where the `\n` comes from is that it's 'left over' from the previous `scanf()` call, which somehow leaves it in the input stream.

Comment: Well that is odd indeed...I did the change and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot your help, it works now!